# Show that this sequence is positive with probability approaching one

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of square integrable real random variables on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$. Suppose that

$$E[X_n\mid \mathcal A]\to 1_A \quad P\text{-a.s.}$$

$$V[X_n\mid \mathcal A]\to 0 \quad P\text{-a.s.}$$

as $n\to \infty$, where $\mathcal A\subset \mathcal F$ is a sub $\sigma$-algebra, and $A\in\mathcal A$ has positive $P$-measure. Can I show then that

$$P[X_n\geq 0]\to 1 \quad \text{as } n\to\infty \quad?$$

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that both those conditions can even happen at the same time if $0<P(A)<1$?

Comment: @Ian If $X_n=1_A$ for all $n$ with $A\in\mathcal A$ then I believe both conditions hold no?

Comment: Never mind, that's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think we can conclude $P(X_n \ge 0) \rightarrow 1$.  Let $\Omega = [0,1]$ with $P$ the Lebesgue measure and $\mathcal A$ the sigma-algebra on $[0,1]$ generated by the Borel subsets of $[0,\frac 12]$.  Let $A = [0,\frac 12]$ and \begin{align*} X_n(x) := \begin{cases} 1 & x \in A \\
\frac 1n & x \in (\frac 12, \frac 34] \\
-\frac 1n & x \in (\frac 34,1] \end{cases}.
\end{align*}
Then $\mathbb{E}[X_n | \mathcal A] = 1_A$ for all $n$ so clearly $\mathbb{E}[X_n | \mathcal A] \rightarrow 1_A$, and $V(X_n | \mathcal A) = \frac{1}{n^2}1_{(\frac 12, 1]} \rightarrow 0$ almost surely.  However, we have $P(X_n < 0) = \frac 14$ for all $n$, so $P(X_n \ge 0) \not \rightarrow 1$.

Comment: Typo: the $0$ at the end should be $1$. Anyway, I suppose an obvious followup is "can you ensure $P(X_n>-\epsilon) \to 1$ for each $\epsilon>0$?"

Comment: Isn't $V(X_n | \mathcal A) = 0$ $P$-a.s. for all $n$?

Comment: @Alphie I think I did make a mistake in $V(X_n|\mathcal A)$, but I don't think it's $0$ a.s. 
 We have $(X_n - \mathbb{E}[X_n|\mathcal A])^2 = (X_n - 1_A)^2 = \frac{1}{n^2} 1_{(\frac 12,1]}$, so $V(X_n|\mathcal A) = \mathbb{E}[(X_n - \mathbb{E}[X_n|\mathcal A])^2|\mathcal A] = \frac{1}{n^2} 1_{(\frac 12,1]}$ which still converges to $0$.

Comment: It seems to me that $\mathbb E[1_{(\frac 12,1]} | \mathcal A]=0$ a.s. no?

Comment: @Alphie No, $(\frac 12,1]$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal A$ because it is $A^c$, and $A$ is $\mathcal A$-measurable.

Comment: Ok I see but then why $\mathbb E[1_{(\frac 12, \frac 34]} | \mathcal A]=0$? Is this why $\mathbb{E}[X_n | \mathcal A] = 1_A$ for all $n$?

Comment: @Alphie No, $\mathbb{E}[1_{(\frac 12, \frac 34]} | \mathcal A] \ne 0$.  The reason we have $\mathbb{E}[X_n | \mathcal A] = 1_A$ for all $n$ is because $\mathbb{E}[1_{(\frac 12, \frac 34]} | \mathcal A] = \mathbb{E}[1_{(\frac 34,1]} | \mathcal A] = \frac 12 1_{(\frac 12,1]}$.  Since the signs are opposite on each of the two sets, they cancel out when computing $\mathbb{E}[X_n | \mathcal A]$.

Comment: I see. And this is because $\mathcal A = \mathcal B[0,\frac 12] \cup \{[0,1]\setminus A:A\in  \mathcal B[0,\frac 12] \}$ so that $\mathbb E [\frac 12 1_{(\frac 12,1]}1_A]=\mathbb E [ 1_{(\frac 12,\frac 34]}1_A]=\mathbb E [ 1_{(\frac 34,1]}1_A]$ for all $A\in\mathcal A$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126734/discussion-between-user6247850-and-alphie).

Answer (score 1):

In general no: let $X_n=\mathbf{1}_A+Y_n$, where $Y_n$ is independent of $\mathcal A$. The first assumption translates as $\mathbb E\left[Y_n\right]\to 0$ and the second one as $\operatorname{Var}(Y_n)\to 0$.

Moreover,
$$
\mathbb P(X_n\geqslant 0)=\mathbb P(A\cap \{1+Y_n\geqslant 0)+\mathbb P(A^c\cap \{Y_n\geqslant 0)
$$
and by independence,
$$
\mathbb P(X_n\geqslant 0)=\mathbb P(A)\mathbb P(1+Y_n\geqslant 0)+\mathbb P(A^c)\mathbb P(Y_n\geqslant 0).
$$
Let $(Y_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ be a sequence of independent random variables such that for each $n$, $Y_n$ taked the values $1/n$ and $-1/n$ with probability $1/2$. Letting $\mathcal A=\sigma(Y_1)$ and $A=\{Y_1=1\}$, the assumptions on  fulfills the assumptions and for $n\geqslant 2$,
$$
\mathbb P(X_n\geqslant 0)=\mathbb P(A\cap \{1+X_n\geqslant 0\})+\mathbb P(A^c\cap \{X_n\geqslant 0\})= \mathbb P(A)+\mathbb P(A^c)/2<1,
$$
as $\mathbb P(1+Y_n\geqslant 0)=1$ and $\mathbb P(Y_n\geqslant 0)=1/2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Two questions: 1) Isn't $\mathbb P(X_n\geqslant 0)= \mathbb P(A)+\mathbb P(A^c)/2$? 2) How do you ensure that $Y_n$ is independent from $\mathcal A$?

Comment: @Alphie Ii have added more details. Actually it seems that $\mathbb P(X_n\geqslant 0)= 1/2$.

Comment: Thank you it is clearer now. I would say that $\mathbb P(1+Y_n\geqslant 0)=1$ so that $\mathbb P(X_n\geqslant 0)= 3/4$.

Comment: Oh you are right, I edited again.